# Sending multiple whatsapp messages using python without reopening browser

Tags: python, whatsapp, whatsapi

I was looking for a way to send WhatsApp messages to more than one user (customer number) without reopening the browser, I came across **Pywhatkit** of whose internal implementation requires reopening the browser every time you want to send a message or media.

Any advice or recommendation of which python tool or library I can use to accomplish this, I will highly appreciate.

Thank you

Comment: I found a way to resolve this by creating an entirely new library  [Alright](https://github.com/Kalebu/alright)

Comment: it is a neat library, but i had to make some changes to work with updated selenium. Also, i had to put the timeout to after sending ENTER key in send_message to allow the message to register as sent

Answer (score -1):

Create the excel file 'messages_schedule.xlsx'

```
import openpyxl
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


# Function to create Excel sheet with sample data
def create_excel_sheet(filename):
    # Create a new Excel workbook
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

    # Select the active sheet
    sheet = wb.active

    # Set column headers
    sheet['A1'] = 'Numbers'
    sheet['B1'] = 'Notes'
    sheet['C1'] = 'Time for Sending'

    # Sample data
    sample_data = [
        ('+923000000000', 'Meeting tomorrow at 2 PM', datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=20)),
        ('+923000000000', 'Don\'t forget to buy groceries', datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=40)),
    ]

    # Populate the sheet with sample data
    for row_num, (number, note, send_time) in enumerate(sample_data, start=2):
        sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=1, value=number)
        sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=2, value=note)
        sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=3, value=send_time)

    # Save the workbook to a file
    wb.save(filename)
    print(f"Excel sheet '{filename}' created with sample data.")


# # Define the filename for the Excel sheet
# excel_filename = 'messages_schedule.xlsx'
#
# # Create Excel sheet with sample data
# create_excel_sheet(excel_filename)
```

send the messages on different times

```
# Importing the Required Library
import pywhatkit
import openpyxl
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
```

for only one message on one number

```
# Defining the Phone Number and Message
phone_number = "+92300000000"
message = "message"

# Sending the WhatsApp Message
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(phone_number, message)

# Displaying a Success Message
print("WhatsApp message sent!")
```

for multiple numbers

```
import create_numbers_xls_sheet

# Define the filename for the Excel sheet
excel_filename = 'messages_schedule.xlsx'

create_numbers_xls_sheet.create_excel_sheet(excel_filename)


# Function to read Excel sheet and schedule messages using pywhatkit
def read_excel_and_schedule_messages(filename):
    # Load the workbook
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    sheet = wb.active

    # Iterate through rows in the sheet
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
        contact, message, send_time = row

        # Calculate the time difference
        current_time = datetime.now()
        time_difference = (send_time - current_time).total_seconds()

        # Wait until the scheduled time
        if time_difference > 0:
            print(f"Waiting for {time_difference} seconds until {send_time}")
            time.sleep(time_difference)

        # Send the message using pywhatkit
        try:
            pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(contact, message)
            print(f"WhatsApp message sent to {contact}: {message}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error sending message to {contact}: {e}")


# Read Excel sheet and schedule messages
read_excel_and_schedule_messages(excel_filename)
```